# Horizontal CollectionView cell with multiple pickerViews drops frames while swiping

Tags: ios, uipickerview, collectionview

I am using a horizontal CollectionView where cell width equals the screen width, paging enabled. Each of the cell contains 5 customized pickerViews and 5 labels.

[image]

I've set isPrefetchingEnabled true. Is there any way to increase the smoothness of the scrolling?

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing cell can improve your scroll performance. Also try running the app on low spec. simulator like SE or 5s to get real like scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done that. No progress.
As I am not loading any heavy data, just some UI elements, I have turned Prefetching Enabled off. It shows a little bit improved performance.